# In Parse Notification, method setDefaultPushCallback from type PushService is not available using android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using Parse Notification in android app, I saw tutorial of Parse Notification where this method setDefaultPushCallback from type PushService is shown but when i use this method in my app, it is not available.

Any Other solution instead of this method how can i implement it ?

MainActivity code:

```
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

    PushService.setDefault
```

Parse App :

```
public class ParseApp extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, "",
            "");

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL,true);
   }
} // Update - code formatting
```

Answer (score 1):

PushService.setDefaultPushCallback() is deprecated now.
So using a custom Parse Broadcast Receiver is the soultion, Add the Following to your manifest file and change the name as well

```
 <receiver android:name="com.yourProject.YourReceiver" android:exported=false>
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also for the Class:

```
public class CustomParseReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {


private Intent parseIntent;

public CustomParseReceiver() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent == null)
        return;

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

        parseIntent = intent;

        Intent broadcast = new Intent("Your Package Name");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
                .sendBroadcast(broadcast.putExtra("message1",""));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("PushJsonException", "" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Add this to your MainActivity

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // When a Push Notification comes, this is called 
       // Call Methods to Update Your Stuff
    }
};
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("Your Package Name"));


}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);

}
```

Comment: And how to call it in MainActivity class

Comment: You can have a broadcast listener in the OnPushReceive method to invoke any methods in the MainActivity when you get a push notification

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Can you give me code demonstrate how to invoke because i have no idea ?

Comment: Do you want to update your app when a push notification comes in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104358/discussion-between-veeresh-charantimath-and-manish-tiwari).